# Wordpress - localhost - cant upload images, search plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

I've seen a handful of people with this exact same issue but nothing I found fixed the issue for me.

I’ve recently created a new WordPress on localhost (wordpress 4.7 on wampserver, windows) with a child theme running off of twentyseventeen main theme. I can access the site itself and the admin dashboard however when I try and access the media library, the **loading spinner just keeps spinning and never loads the library**.

From within a page/post/library I can upload a media file but get an error on the front end of the dashboard: **‘An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.’**

If I look in the uploads folder the image is there along with all size variations.

I also can’t search for a plugin, when I enter a search term it just keeps showing the loading spinner and nothing ever happens.

Another user had the same issue but said changing the .php file encoding to utf-8 with BOM fixed his issue. I tried encoding all to utf-8 with and without BOM but neither worked.

Someone has to have been able to fix this issue, any ideas?

Comment: Checked the console for front end errors and the server logs for back end errors?

Comment: If the images are being uploaded then you should change your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, everything was good. There was no issues with local permissions, no additional plugins were causing any errors either. I decided to lose the twentyseventeen theme and use the naked theme as the base for my custom child theme and the problem was solved. There seams to be something wrong with the twentyseventeen theme. Atleast running locally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have correct rights for writing files... did you check your CHMOD ?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: _"If I look in the uploads folder the image is there along with all size variations."_